# Git - log entries missing after merge

Tags: git, merge, intellij-idea, git-merge, git-log

I seem to have corrupted my Git repository after a merge that somehow went wrong. What I did was:

- `git checkout` <main branch>
- `git merge` <feature branch>
- I got a lot of conflicts which I resolved via Git Extension/kdiff
- After the last conflict was resolved Git Extensions asked me if I wanted to commit. I answered "No" since I wanted to check the merge result a bit more before commiting.
- I then used "Update Project" in IntelliJ to pull the latest changes from the central repository so my upcoming `git push` would not be rejected. I think "Updated Project" in IntelliJ does something similar to `git stash; git pull --rebase; git stash apply`.

  The "Update Project" command gave no warnings, errors or merge conflicts.

  I'm guessing that this step is the source of my problems -- Git somehow lost track of the ongoing merge.
- I then commited the merge and pushed it to the central repository

When I use Git Extensions to browse the repository history I now see two problems:

- Git does not seem to recognize that the feature branch has been merged into the main branch.

  The result of the merge is fine, but the graphical representation of the branching history in Git Extensions shows no line from the feature branch to the main branch. The log entry for my merge commit just continues from the main branch like a regular non-merge commit.
- When I do "git log -- <file that was changed in feature branch>" it does not show log entries for all commits that actually changed the file.

  For some files log entries for changes done on the feature branch before the merge are missing.

  For other files, the log entry for my merge commit is missing even though the file was modified during conflict resolution.

  I can see the missing log entries if I use "git log --full-history".

Can anyone explain what went wrong and what I can do to fix the problem? I spent several hours fixing the merge conflicts and if possible I would like to keep the merge result without redoing everything again.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `git reflog` and revert to the last known good state before the merge?

Comment: Thanks - Yes, I know I can roll back, although it will be problematic since the bad commit has already been pushed. Also, I would like to keep the result of the merge without redoing everything again.